# package-install is "checking" a lot of files

Tags: package

On running `(package-install <some-pkg-name>)`, I am seeing a long list of messages of the form `Checking /some/path/to/a/file`. What are these checks that `package-install` does? How can I exclude certain locations that I see are irrelevant and have no `.el` files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not `package.el`.  Grepping sources reveals it's  `bytecomp.el` generating that message in `byte-recompile-directory`.  If you consider the usecase of that (interactive) function, it makes a lot of sense to display every directory and subdirectory containing recompilable files:  It is typically used during development and Emacs bootstrapping to have an idea what generates warnings and fails compiling cleanly.

Back to `package.el`.  I consider reusing `byte-recompile-directory` for the installation of a package plain wrong.  An user does not care about how lenient the developer of a package has been with regards to warnings and does not need a compilation buffer to pop up at them.  It would have been better to reconsider how one would properly solve that usecase and write a better abstraction for it, but that hasn't happened yet.  After all, `package.el` works well enough, save the occasional bug...

If you strongly care about these messages, I recommend discussing it on [emacs-devel](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/).

Comment: I agree that Emacs is over-eagerly invoking `byte-recompile-directory`. Compilation should be a user decision. It would be OK for `package.el` to do it optionally.